# Draw route on map without MapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw a path on map between known points(lat, long) using:

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr="+source_latitude+","+source_longitude+"&daddr="+destination_latitude+","+destination_longitude;
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

But instead of just drawing route, Google Maps shows menu Car/Bus/By foot, trying to make a route from my current location to those points. What am I doing wrong? Is it still possible to draw route on map using the method above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By running this intent you are basically opening an "outside" application - Google Maps that is not related to your application. the behavior you are receiving is the behavior that should be for the version of Google Maps you have in your phone. You can't edit the way it behaves, only the things that you are allowed to change using the settings screen of this application.

Comment: I also tried to open this link in a webview, the same result. Interesting that browser on pc draws lines, as I wanted.

Comment: again, as I said, using this link you are running the google maps application and you can't modify it. to modify the map you have to build you own map application.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the xml or json that your are using in the url in an Asynctask class and draw it on the map.